# Pickle models according to their feature set

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle

I have a REST service that applies a classifier to user data. I subset my feature space and train a model according to which subset of features are available in the user's data. I want to cache/pickle the models once they've been created. How can I store these models so that I can always recover the right one?

One model might be:

```
['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature10']
```

and another model might be defined by:

```
['feature1', 'feature9'].
```

I'm considering hashing this list, and then pickling the model with:

```
pickle(filename=hash(set(feature_list)), model=model)
```

Is this appropriate? Will I always get back the intended model? Would it be better to pickle a dictionary of type Dict[Set[features], model]?

Comment: Why not append the feature ids as strings something like `model_with_features_1_2_10`

Comment: @VivekKumar interesting. So I guess I need to make a permanent map from feature name to integer ID, and make sure that file names put the integers in order. Kinda awkward to parse though right?